# Problems in Using QML Desktop Components in Release Mode

Tags: release, desktop, qml

I wanted to write c++ desktop application with fine UI, so I did it in QT Creator.

Then I decided to add some UI features, and I moved to QML(QT Quick Application).

I installed QML Desktop Components according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298584/installing-qt-quick-components-for-desktop-for-use-with-qt-creator) instructions, used `import Qt.labs.components 0.1` and it worked well.but now I have to deploy my application, and I noticed that the application runs only on Debug mode, and not on Release mode. I checked, and saw that I have just the styleplugind.dll, and not the styleplugin.dll. Shortly, I have only the debug dll, and not the release one. I installed the components again,for release, and I really got the styleplugin.dll. but when I'm running my application(I remembered adding CONFIG+=release to my .pro file),I'm getting this error:

```
loaded for module "Qt.labs.components": The plugin 'C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/imports/Qt/labs/components/plugin/styleplugin.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. Expected build key "Windows mingw release full-config", got "Windows mingw debug full-config" 
 import Qt.labs.components 0.1 
 ^
```

I don't understand why I'm getting that: I have the right .dll file, and everything seems okay.

(BTW, I'm on Windows7)

What should I do??

Comment: Well, the error output states that you styleplugin.dll is still build in debug mode...

Comment: You're right, @sebasgo, I compiled it again, removed the previous debug dlls, and it works now!!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @sebasgo please post this as an answer so the user can accept

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as the error output states, that your styleplugin.dll is still build against an incompatible Qt build (`debug`, expected is `release`).