# Error while running QML desktop application in release mode

Tags: qt, dll, desktop, qml

I wrote a QML desktop application in Qt and c++, and used Qt Quick Desktop Components for UI features.(Windows 7). I've installed the components according to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298584/installing-qt-quick-components-for-desktop-for-use-with-qt-creator) instrucions(first answer), once with the commands:qmake, jom debug , jom install, and once with:qmake, jom release, jom install.

I have both styleplugin.dll and styleplugind.dll(for release mode and for debug mode), but when I'm running my application in release mode, I'm getting this error:

> loaded for module "Qt.labs.components": The plugin 'C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/imports/Qt/labs/components/plugin/styleplugin.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. Expected build key "Windows mingw release full-config", got "Windows mingw debug full-config" 
>    import Qt.labs.components 0.1 
>    ^

Do you know about any reason for this situation?

any answer will be appreciated!

Comment: I think its trying to access the library which you have built for debug mode. Just remove or move the debug built library file to a different folder while keeping the release mode dll. And then try running the application.

Comment: Thanks, @Raja Varma, it really tried to. and I installed it again,moved the debug files - and it works!!!

Comment: @user1835297 you've previously posted a similar question, please delete this one