# Getting an empty window while Deploying a QML Desktop application on Windows

Tags: qt, deployment, desktop, qml

I just finished writing a QML desktop application(with QtCreator and c++) on Windows.

I've installed QT Quick Desktop Components, according to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298584/installing-qt-quick-components-for-desktop-for-use-with-qt-creator) instrctions, with MinGw compiler, in C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\imports\Qt\labs\components folder.

I installed it twice - once for debug - with the command: qmake && jom debug && jom install, and once for release - with the command: qmake && jom release && jom install, so I have now two dll files: 1.styleplugin.dll, 2.styleplugind.dll. and I'm using each of them when I need it. I've imported it to my application with:

> import Qt.labs.components 0.1

Now I have to deploy my application, and make it work on all the machines: with Qt installed on it, or with no.I tried to do it with [these](http://www.johanpaul.com/blog/2011/07/deploying-qt-and-qt-quick-applications-on-windows/) steps:

coppied these files: application.exe, QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll, QtNetwork4.dll, styleplugin.dll and styleplugind.dll.

but when I'm running the .exe file - I'm getting a white, empty screen.

(BTW, when I'm running the .exe file from it's release folder - I can see again only a white window, and when I did the same to a simple Widget GUI application - it runs well from there).

Do you know about any reason to this situation?

Any answer would be appreciated!

Comment: Ad what's the output in your application log? I bet it would help you to find the solution

Comment: Qt Creator's default run configuration runs the .exe from project/, not from project/release/, and if the .qml file lookup is done relative to the .exe run path, the .qml files may not be found. Try moving the .exe one folder up and check the run configuration settings (to see if setting run path to /release breaks things in the same way you see on target)

Comment: Please respond to answers or accept them

Answer (score 2):

May be you forgot deploy QML files to exe? (qrc)

Simple way to test it, is to copy the folder with qml-files to destination near `.exe` file.

Please read [Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html) documentation:

I.e.

- First need add new "Resource File" in project menu,
- Then place **all** of your qml files into this resource file
- Change "Source" in your `QDeclarativeView` like this:

  ```
  viewer->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to enable warnings by running the command

```
qmlviewer.exe -warnings show qmlfilename.qml
```

If qmlviewer cannot find any dependent import libraries, it will show up here.

To make sure qmlviewer can access the import libraries either use the -I <directory> on the command line 
OR set the QML_IMPORT_PATH environment variable to the folder containing the import libs.

eg:

```
qmlviewer.exe -warnings show -I <directory> qmlfilename.qml
```

OR

```
set QML_IMPORT_PATH=<directory>
```

where <directory> is the module import search path (without the  <>)