# QT5- Installing Qt Quick Components for Desktop

Tags: qml, qt-creator, qt5, qqmlcomponent

I have some installation issues with the Qt Quick Components for Desktop, using QT5.

Following are the steps I have followed (based on [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298584/installing-qt-quick-components-for-desktop-for-use-with-qt-creator/9464679#9464679)):

1. Downloaded the tar.gz from http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/desktop/trees/master, and unpacked the components.
2. Added to `PATH` variable value in the environment variables (OS : Windows 8) `C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2012_opengl\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin;`
3. Run the `vcvars32.bat` script (Visual Studio 2012).
4. Ran the command: `qmake && nmake install` in `\qt-components-desktop\components` folder.
5. Ran the command: `qmake && nmake install` in `\qt-components-desktop\src` folder. This command has automatically copied the compiled component files to QT import folder.

During step **5**, I got these errors:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/qmenu.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/qmenu.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/qgraphicsitem.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/QStyle': No such file or directory
.\qdeclarativefolderlistmodel.cpp(162) : error C3861: 'setRoleNames': identifier not found
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/QStyle': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/qgraphicssceneevent.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/QAction': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/QApplication': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2' Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2' Stop.
```

I understand that these errors are occurred because the source code is for QT4, and these include deceleration (like `QtGui/QApplication`) are no longer exist in QT5.

I googled a lot, but I couldn't find how can I download this plugin for QT5, as in http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/desktop/trees/master for QT4.

Any idea? or maybe there is another issue that I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the alternative components in QT5:

according to [this wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtDesktopComponents), `Qt Quick Controls` replaced the former one `Qt Desktop Components`. So for using these components when porting QML code from QT4.x to QT5.x, you need to replace `import Qt.labs.components *version*`in your QML file with `import QtQuick.Controls *version*`.

Hope this will help someone...